# Setting time in milliseconds to Central European Time (CET)

Tags: php, time, timezone

The following piece of code is retuning the time (for a future date) in milliseconds:

```
<?php echo strtotime(str_replace("-","/",$_product->getDateEnd()))*1000 ?>
```

How could I adjust the code in a way that it would return the time in milliseconds for the CET time zone, given the fact that `strtotime` seems to be timezone unaware?

`<?php echo $_product->getDateEnd(); ?>` is returning something like: `2019-02-14 00:00:00`

Thanks for your input and collaborations

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
    echo strtotime('2019-02-14 00:00:00')*1000;
```

'CEST' is not a supported timezone